# Covariance matrix in non linear mixed effects matlab

Tags: matlab, effects, covariance, mixed

I'm wondering if someone is familiar with the NLMEFITSA algorithm in matlab. This algorithm gives me as result the fixed effects parameters (beta) for a mixed effects model as well as their covariance matrix (psi), but it also gives me, in the "stats" struct, one covariance matrix called "covb" I know this one has to do with the standard errors and it is important for calculating confidence intervals, but to be honest I don't know what is exactly the difference between this "covb" and the "psi " covariance matrix. And how could I use "covb" when simulating new data?